# Sorting date from a table

Tags: postgresql, greatest-n-per-group

I have the following table in PostgreSQL and I want to display the maximum sale figure of each fname along with the relevant saledate. Please help me with the solution code.

```
CREATE TABLE CookieSale (
  ID VARCHAR(4),
  fname VARCHAR(15),
  sale FLOAT,
  saleDate DATE
);

INSERT INTO CookieSale
VALUES
('E001', 'Linda', 1000.00, '2016-01-30'),
('E002', 'Sally', 750.00, '2016-01-30'),
('E003', 'Zindy', 500.00, '2016-01-30'),
('E001', 'Linda', 150.00, '2016-02-01'),
('E001', 'Linda', 5000.00, '2016-02-01'),
('E002', 'Sally', 250.00, '2016-02-01'),
('E001', 'Linda', 250.00, '2016-02-02'),
('E002', 'Sally', 150.00, '2016-02-02'),
('E003', 'Zindy', 50.00, '2016-02-02');
```

I tried with

```
SELECT fname, MAX(sale), saleDate 
FROM CookieSale;
```

I need the results to be like

```
"Lynda | 5000.00 | 2016-02-01"
```

Comment: Please consider adding some explanation and details to your answer and show us what have you tried that we could look.

Comment: I tried with SELECT fname, MAX(sale), saleDate FROM CookieSale;

Comment: Could you add a sample of desired result ?

Comment: I need the results to be like "Lynda | 5000.00 | 2016-02-01"

Comment: I will try it, hope it will work, thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

Your description and expected results are inconsistent. Description says "maximum sale figure of each fname" but expected results indicates only the maximum overall. And neither has anything to do with the Title. Please try being a little more consistent.  
I'll take description as what is actually wanted. For that use the Window function RANK within a sub select and the outer select just take rank 1.

```
select fname, sale, saledate
  from ( select cs.*, rank() over (partition by fname order by fname, sale desc) rk
           from cookiesales cs
       ) csr          
 where rk = 1;
```